# Changing cell when a cell next to it changes

Tags: excel, vba

Consider there are three columns in a sheet.
[image]

If there is any change in columns B or D then the data should be printed in column E only for the changed row.

Conditions are:

- if B = Process and D = ADD then in E = MfgddnS,
- if B = Process and D = REMOVE then in E = MetrhS,

  - ELSE NOTHING,
- if B = TOOL and D = ADD then in E = Mfgd,
- if B = TOOL and D = REMOVE then in E = Met,

  - ELSE NOTHING.

I managed to make that happen by clicking the button, not automatically, also it changes every cell in the column E, not in the changed row only. So, if you got any idea mention it.

```vb
Sub effected()    
    Dim R As Long, Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    For R = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Ws.Range("B" & R).Value = "Process" And Ws.Range("D" & R).Value = "ADD" Then
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Value = "MfgddnS"
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Interior.ColorIndex = 41
        ElseIf Ws.Range("B" & R).Value = "Process" And Ws.Range("D" & R).Value = "REMOVE" Then
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Value = "MetrhS"
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ElseIf Ws.Range("B" & R).Value = "Process" And Ws.Range("D" & R).Value = "MODIFY" Then
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Value = "qeth"
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        Else
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Value = "NOTHING"
            Ws.Range("E" & R).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a formula in E?

Comment: ...and set Conditional Formatting-Highlight Cell Rules-Equal To by value to column E?

Comment: using formula may cause problems in long term usage and also if the conditions increases then it will get complicated. so, i thought it will be easy to use vba

Comment: Do you want it to happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("D:D"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        Dim changedCell As Range
        For Each changedCell In Intersect(Range("D:D"), Target).Cells
       If changedCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Process" And changedCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = "ADD" Then
             changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "MfgddnS"
             changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 41
            Else
             changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Nothing"
             changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4


      End If
        Next changedCell
    End If
End Sub
```

only question is how can i mention B Column in the code

Comment: You seem to already know that, with the `Offset(0, -2)`? Or with `Application.Intersect(changedCell.EntireRow, Me.Columns("B"))`? Or `Me.Columns("B").Cells(changedCell.Row)`? Or `changedCell.EntireRow.Cells(2)`? Just change all `Range` to `Me.Range` in your code.